# dartdoc failed: Top level package requires Flutter but FLUTTER_ROOT environment variable not set

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

I am trying to run dartdoc for my flutter package but I am getting this,

```
dartdoc failed: Top level package requires Flutter but FLUTTER_ROOT environment variable not set.
```

How to add FLUTTER_ROOT environment variable <strike>as I have already added environment variable for Flutter SDK and that's working fine</strike>, I am just getting issue while running `dartdoc`. I am a Linux user.

Comment: Are you sure that `FLUTTER_ROOT` is set?  From the same terminal where you ran `dartdoc`, does `echo $FLUTTER_ROOT` print anything?  Related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24808

Comment: Thanks, I solved it, actually, I only added the flutter path but not `FLUTTER_ROOT` environment variable.

Comment: If someone has landed here searching a solution for Windows (my case) just got to the properties of the pc and add the environment variable directly. Close and open your terminal :D

Answer (score 19):

try running `flutter pub global run dartdoc:dartdoc` instead

Comment: `flutter pub global activate dartdoc` to setup

Answer (score 10):

If you wish to generate API documentation locally on your development machine, use the following commands:

1. Change directory to the location of your package:

```
cd ~/dev/mypackage
```

2. Tell the documentation tool where the Flutter SDK is located (change the following commands to reflect where you placed it):

```
export FLUTTER_ROOT=~/dev/flutter  # on macOS or Linux  
set FLUTTER_ROOT=~/dev/flutter     # on Windows
```

3. Run the dartdoc tool (included as part of the Flutter SDK), as follows:

```
$FLUTTER_ROOT/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/resources/dartdoc   # on macOS or Linux  
%FLUTTER_ROOT%\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\resources\dartdoc   # on Windows
```

link https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages